# Adding a 'rest'-group with Pandas value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I just started working with the pandas library to analyze large datasets. I am analyzing creditcard data that has the property `issuercountrycode`, that consists out of 117 possibilities. When trying to visualize what `issuercountrycode` are used in my dataset, I currently use the following code to generate a piechart.

```
df['issuercountrycode'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie')
plt.show()
```

This results in the following piechart:

[image: Example of my piechart]

As you can see, this isn't ideal because multiple values are not used that often. Is there a possibility in pandas to, when using the value_counts() function, add a threshold, and add values that are lower than a certain value to a 'rest' group? Are these type of operations even possible in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need count it with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and `sum`:

```
tresh = 2
a = df['issuercountrycode'].value_counts()
b = a[a > tresh]
b['rest'] = a[a <= tresh].sum()
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(10)
L = list('abcdef')
df = pd.DataFrame({'issuercountrycode':np.random.choice(L, size=15)})

tresh = 2
a = df['issuercountrycode'].value_counts()
b = a[a > tresh]
b['rest'] = a[a <= tresh].sum()
print (b)
b       5
f       3
a       3
rest    4
Name: issuercountrycode, dtype: int64

b.plot.pie()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Glad can help, nice weekend!